# How to display the collection of objects with for each loop in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to display data from database in the browser with Spring MVC. Everything is alright, except my Thymeleaf template for each loop. Something is wrong there.

How can I display `id` data in **ID** row and `name` data in **Name** row iterating through the collection of objects with *for each* loop?

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
     <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr style="font-size: 13">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="count :  ${id}">
            <td><p th:text="${count}" /></td>       
            <td><p th:text="${name}" /></td>        

        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, as you didn't specify your `count` object, and didn't show your controller.

Well supposing you have some entity `Count` with fields `id` and `name`, which you persist in the corresponding table of your database, and which you want to display in the Thymeleaf template.

To retrieve data from the database you need some **Service** or **Repository** class, that should have method that returns a `List` of your entities, example of such service method `listAll()`:

```
public List<Count> listAll() {
    List<Count> counts = new ArrayList<>();
    countRepository.findAll().forEach(counts::add);
    return counts;
}
```

Then you you need to set up the *request mapping* in your controller and add in that method an attribute to the `model` object, that will be a result of execution `listAll()` method. It may be done like:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
public String countsList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("counts", countService.listAll());
    return "list";
}
```

Finally answering your question, your `list.html` template should contain the block:

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(counts)}">
    <h2>Counts List</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="count : ${counts}">
            <td th:text="${count.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${count.name}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Read more info in Thymeleaf Documentation - [Iteration Basics](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics) section.

Comment: Sorry for that.. but you did  a great job ! it's all what i need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice work putting the how-to info in start-to-finish order.  Exactly what I was searching for.  Even though I only needed the last part, this is an extremely helpful format.

Comment: How can i print a list inside count. for example count.someList